# Is there a system call to run systemctl in C program (not the system() function)?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, system, systemctl

I am on a Ubuntu 22.04 server. I want to run:

```
systemctl restart someService
```

but want to do so in a C program.

Intuitively I tried:

```
system("systemctl restart someService")
```

This did not work even if my program itself has setUid set to root as systemctl does not itself have setUid bit set to root.

I would like to write a program and set its uid to root so that anyone can execute it to restart a certain system service. This is only possible by using some direct function and not the system call as done above.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try specifying the complete path to `systemctl` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried [execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and friends? If you need to wait for the result, you might have to combine it with [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: The [system](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) manpage specifically recommends _not_ calling it from a set-uid as root binary

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya  I do not want to use system() call anyway so I agree with your suggestion. I did not think of execve and friends but still I will need a system() call. In any event, I am looking for a function call (other than system()) to execute it as a native function.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya As example, how do I execute **systemctl restart sshd** from a C program?

Comment: @konsolebox  I did not try specifying the full path of systemctl but I had tried other executables (with full path ) which did not have setuid set to root but the calling program had setUid set to root.  In any event, why would setting full path make a difference when there is no other systemctl in the PATH?

Comment: Maybe PATH gets reset. It's just about removing unnecessary possibilities.

Comment: @konsolebox using `system` invokes the command through `/bin/sh` which on some distributions resets the user.

Comment: It looks like you are solving a wrong problem. If you make your program create a dummy file say `/tmp/dummy`, will it be owned by root?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Right. Intuitively the next thing to do is call the binary directly with some exec functions. Keep narrowing it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a system-call that can do the job of systemctl in general. I think your approach of calling the `systemctl` command from your program is correct. But, I am not getting into the security considerations here. You should be really careful when writing set-uid programs.

Now, the main issue with your code is that [`system`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) should not be used from set-uid binaries because it doesn't let you control the environment variables, which can be set maliciously before calling your program to change the behavior of the called process. Besides that, the `system` command calls `/bin/sh` to run your command which on some versions of Linux drop privilege as mentioned on the man-page linked above. The right approach would be to use [`execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) family of functions that offer more control and do not spawn a shell. What you need to do can be done in the following way -

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setuid(0);
    setgid(0);
    char *newargv[] = {"/usr/bin/systemctl", "restart", "someService", NULL};
    char *newenviron[] = { NULL };
    execve(newargv[0], newargv, newenviron);
    perror("execve");   /* execve() returns only on error */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Notice the empty (or pure) environment above. It is worth noting that the `execve` should not return unless there is an error. If you need to wait for the return value from the `systemctl` command, you might have to combine this with [`fork`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: Worked perfectly but I set the uid on the executable after changing ownership to root rather than using setuid(), setgid().

Comment: @Sunny there is a difference between the effective user id (the id set when you use setuid) and the uid a program is running as. You can call `setuid(0)` only if you have the right privileges, one of which is to have the effective uid set to 0

Comment: But to execute setuid(0) you will need to have the uid of the program running to be of root too. So I am missing the advantage of using setuid()

Comment: @Sunny not really, you can `setuid(0)` if just your _effective_ uid is 0 (which is different from the uid, and is set when your binary has the +s flag)

Comment: My earlier comment should have been: "But to execute setuid(0) you will need to have the **effective** uid of the program..." My argument still is, if effective uid is set to 0, why is there a need for using setuid(0) again in the program?"

Comment: @Sunny, Right! The intention was to also the "real" UID and the "real" GID to 0 (which would be otherwise set to your user id). These are mostly not relevant, except for file access. I am not sure if `systemctl` accesses files, but this is common practice when you want the program to run exactly like root. More about [`setuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)